# Mapping in map in json response

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I need to parse json api response, with response.data equals:

```
[
    {
      "name": "Programming",
      "subcategories": [
        {"name": "web-development"},
        {"name": "backend-development"},
        {"name": "data-scince"}
      ]
    },{
      "name": "Design",
      "subcategories": [
        {"name": "Graphic-design"},
        {"name": "Motion-design"},
        {"name": "3D modeling"}
  ]
```

and I need to return one array[String] with all subcategories, ex ["web-development", "backend-development" ... "3D modeling"]

All that I did is:

```
let subs = categories.data.map(function(category) {
                    return category.subcategories.map(function(subcategory) {
                        return subcategory.name
                    })
                    })
```

and it returns Array of arrays with categories. Im sure, that there near a better and easier way. Thanks!

Comment: Is `response` the same thing as `categories`? NB: the fact that this array comes from an API response seams irrelevant to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let data = [{
  "name": "Programming",
  "subcategories": [{
      "name": "web-development"
    },
    {
      "name": "backend-development"
    },
    {
      "name": "data-scince"
    }
  ]
}, {
  "name": "Design",
  "subcategories": [{
      "name": "Graphic-design"
    },
    {
      "name": "Motion-design"
    },
    {
      "name": "3D modeling"
    }
  ]
}]

let subs = data.flatMap(function(category) {
  return category.subcategories.map(function(subcategory) {
    return subcategory.name
  })
})

console.log(subs)
```

Try using Array [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Answer (score 2):

You can get a flat array by replacing:

```
categories.data.map
```

with

```
categories.data.flatMap
```